# Polymorphism and the new operator [C++]

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I am working on an api, which during runtime decides which higher-level api to use, I have many abstract classes, and derived classes for each high-level api, and a context class which provides me with the correct derived classes for the job, using a function (for example):

```
Mesh* genMesh(data d) { if(m_useA_API) return new A_mesh(d); else return B_mesh(d); }
```

something like that, now the question is, is it possible to make the code less ugly ? and instead of using methods inside the context class, can I override new operator in the base class to return the appropriate derived class instance?

if not, what are some possible solutions?

tl;dr this is what i'd like to do

```
Mesh* m = new Mesh(data); // and the base class decides which derived class to use instead of the Context class.
```

Thanks.

Comment: The new operator is for raw storage allocation. It's not a hook for factory functions.

Comment: Yes, that's why I came on stackoverflow for help, new returns a memory block, I'm looking to see if there are solutions for this problem.

Comment: There is no solution to your question as asked.   There are various approaches and design patterns for implementing factories more effectively.    But there is no solution that causes `Mesh *m = new Mesh(data)` to result in `m` pointing at an instance of some class derived from `Mesh`.   The `new` expression, by definition, creates an instance of `Mesh`, not one of its derived classes.

Comment: Your solution is not actually ugly. It is a [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and it seems to be suitable for your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `new` as factory, but you could use Implementation Pattern for it:

```
class Mesh {
  std::unique_ptr<MeshImpl> _impl;
public:
  Mesh(int data)
  : _impl(
    m_use_A_API
      ? new A_mesh(data)
      : new B_mesh(data)
  ) {
  }
  MeshImpl& get_value() { return *_impl; } 
};
```

Classes `A_mesh`, `B_mesh` are different classes that inherited from class `MeshImpl` and will be initialized by correct way;

Or you can improve your factory code by next way:

1. move your method `genMesh(int)` inside class `Mesh`
2. make constructors of `Mesh` private, for be sure that nobody call it directly.

Comment: I seem to have missed a simple solution! thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw owning pointer. (so you won't break rule of 3/5/0).

Comment: If constructors of `Mesh` are private, it will not be possible to create instances of derived classes (`A_Mesh`, etc).   Construction of a derived class always invokes/calls a constructor of a base class.  Using the approach here will result in infinite recursion if derived class constructors call `Mesh(int)`.

Comment: That's not what knst's implementation does, MeshImp is not a derivative of Mesh, MeshImp is a different type A_mesh and B_mesh are derivatives of MeshImp, I thought about this approach before but didn't write it down and just forgot about it, this is why I should start using design documents!